# Spring MVC bindingresult haserror return

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I want to return http error or exit from method when bindingresult haserror active .How i can do it ?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Node create(@Valid @RequestBody Node node, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Create new Node: %s", node));
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return nodeService.create(node);
        }
        else{
            // How i can exit without return any Node object ?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return null.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Node create(@Valid @RequestBody Node node, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Create new Node: %s", node));
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return nodeService.create(node);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it doesnt create new node when has error ;)